# Torch Caffe Lua - How to get Flickr Style Example to work?

Tags: lua, caffe, torch

Using the [Torch Caffe Binding](https://github.com/szagoruyko/torch-caffe-binding). I want to make a prediction on the [Flickr Style example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html). I've got the trained model and the code below. How do I have to alter the code to make it work?

```
require 'caffe'
require 'image'

-- test flickr_style single image
-- configuaration
caffe_path = '/home/user/caffe/'
data_path = caffe_path..'data/flickr_style/images/'
file_name = data_path..'614893901_c9ed490f80.jpg'

-- caffe in CPU mode
caffe.Net.setModeCPU()

-- initialize net
net = caffe.Net(caffe_path..'models/finetune_flickr_style/deploy.prototxt', caffe_path..'models/finetune_flickr_style/finetune_flickr_style.caffemodel','test')

-- load and resize image
input = torch.FloatTensor(10,3,227,227)
img = image.load(file_name,3,'float')
img = image.scale(img,227,227)

for i=1,3 do
  for j=1,32 do
    for k=1,32 do
      input[1][i][j][k] = img[i][j][k]
    end
  end
end

-- predict result
output = net:forward(input)
print(output[1])
y,j = torch.max(output[1],1)
print('Class: ', j[1][1][1] , y[1][1][1])
```

To output now is a FloatTensor [torch.FloatTensor of dimension 20x1x1] with 20 times NaN values.

Comment: @hjpotter92, why the edit in the code? j[1][3][1], y[1][4][1] give "out of range" error.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was introduced because of buggy behaviour of mark down editor.